# How can I set an @input property in Angularjs 2 on javascript (no typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-components

Angularjs 2 [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html) has description how to set an input variable for a component on TypeScript

```
export class HeroDetailComponent {
  @Input()
  hero: Hero;
}
```

since that the documentation for javascipt isn't available yet, I'm stuck with setting the component variable via javascript, here is the code for the component that should receive hero variable as an input, haw can I set it?

```
(function (app) {
    app.HeroDetailComponent = ng.core.Component({
        selector: 'hero-detail',
        template: `<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
        <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
                <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
                <div>
                    <label>name: </label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
                </div>
                </div>`
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function(){

        }
    })
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

using the component `<hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></hero-detail>`
Since the property **hero** isn't set browser fires the following error
`Can't bind to 'hero' since it isn't a known property of 'hero-detail'`

Comment: What about `<hero-detail [hero]="someProp">`?

Comment: yes, I'm going to use the component this way but since the *hero* property is not set inside the component the browser returns the following error: Can't bind to 'hero' since it isn't a known property of 'hero-detail'

Comment: "but since the hero property is not set inside the component" I don't understand what you mean by this. You need to register it with directives or `@NgModule()` so the component gets instantiated, then you can use binding to it's inputs and outputs. Why don't you use TS instead of JS?